# sql datetime overflow

Tags: sql-server-2005, ado.net, c#-4.0

net and I'm trying to insert a row into an entity, and I keep getting the following error:

SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Here's my code on C# side:

```
        public static void DumpToLog(string s, string userID)
    {
        var ler = new LoggedExceptionRepository();
        var lex = new LoggedException();
        lex.loginID = userID;
        lex.dateTime = DateTime.Now;
        lex.text = s;
        ler.Add(lex);
        ler.Save();
    }
```

I've tried running sql server profiler and the only thing it executes is teh following (which if I execute directly against the sql server, it works!!):

```
    exec sp_executesql N'insert [dbo].[LoggedExceptions]([text], [loginID], [dateTime])
values (@0, @1, @2)
select [ID]
from [dbo].[LoggedExceptions]
where @@ROWCOUNT > 0 and [ID] = scope_identity()',N'@0 nvarchar(max) ,@1 varchar(50),@2 datetime',@0=N'payment failed, rv = 0',@1='riz',@2='2010-11-03 12:05:00:690'
```

any suggestions as to what I can do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the issue. I just didn't realize that I was creating new objects and assigning them to existing entities earlier in teh code.  so when it was saving the datacontext, it was having a problem with those earlier entities.

Answer (score 0):

does it work if you hardcode the date parameter value?  there could be something else going on, or it could be a misleading message.

Comment: yep i tried that.  like i said, the sql that it generates executes fine against the database.  i don't know what exactly is generating that error.

Comment: you could try hardcoding the loginID and text as a date, too, to see if the sequence of parameter values is getting messed up

Comment: that's not possible because the code to insert into the database is generated by the entity framework

Comment: and it couldn't behave unexpectedly?  it's just something else to try.  if it fixes it, it gives you more information about what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Is there another datetime column in LoggedExceptions that you're not setting? There are cases where a framework will use `DateTime.MinValue` to fill in unspecified columns. Try setting explicit values for all datetime columns in LoggedExceptions.